# Why is が not being used in this sentence?

Tags: particles

> A: あの～、すみません。
>   B: はい。
>   A: このへんにこうしゅうでんわはありますか。
>   <sub>[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBP9K.png)</sub>

In the third sentence, は is used instead of が, but こうしゅうでんわ is something new being added to the conversation, which is a function of が.

Comment: Related? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18573/9831

Comment: I guess that one way to look at it is that in Xはありますか you clearly know what X is, and you are assuming that the listener also knows what X is (if not then there would be no point asking the question), therefore X is already in the universe of discourse, so は is the correct particle.

Comment: Please transcribe images of text. Images are not searchable, among other issues.